# Handle / Log Exceptions that are caught in the whole application

Tags: php, laravel, exception

I am currently maintaining a application with a large code base. The application is still under development.

My goal is to log all the exceptions that are thrown in the application. Also the ones that are caught in the try catch block. Due to the large code base I cannot add single lines of code in the catch blocks or create my custom exception class.

The way I tried to solve it or look for a solution are:

- Listen for class construction in the whole application
- Override the Exception class (can't do this because it is an core php class)

My most recent code that I tried is:
My test exception (`dashboardcontroller.php`)

```
try {
        throw new \Exception('custom thrown exception');
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        Log::info('Exception caught');
    }
```

`Exceptions\Handler.php`

```
public function report(Exception $exception)
    {
        Log::info($exception);
        parent::report($exception);
    }
```

`Log`

```
[2020-03-10 17:19:09] local.INFO: Exception caught
```

So the question is: How can I log / handle thrown exceptions that are caught in the try catch block without adding code that requires lot of changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: You can't <sup>(as far as I know that is)</sup>.

Exceptions that are caught are, normally, caught *for a reason*; they are handled (or: they *should* be) in the catch-statement (i.e. exception handler). It's the *uncaught* exceptions that you want to log.

Exceptions should never be used for program-flow, but it does happen anyway and sometimes for good reason:

```
if (fileExists('foo.txt')) {
  fileDelete('foo.txt'); // May result in a race-condition
}
```

V.s.:

```
try {
  fileDelete('foo.txt')
catch (IOException) {
  // NO-OP
}
```

Another common pattern:

```
while (true) {
  try {
    item = queue.Receive(10); // Wait max. 10 seconds
    process(item);            // Process item
  } catch (TimeOutException) {
    // Nothing on queue, handle other stuff and then continue waiting...
    DoStuff();
  }
}
```

Above patterns are quite common. Again: exceptions shouldn't be used for program-flow and the queue example above surely shouldn't exist but the reality is that it happens. Real world applications, libraries, API's etc. sometimes just work that way and as soon as you're dealing with *3rd party* applications, libraries or API's you're in trouble because you can't always change everything to what you would *like* it to be.

Can you imagine your logfile in the above queue-example with your 'generic application wide catch logger' for an application running 24/7?

When to log an exception (and maybe just as important: *what* to log) *should* be considered on a case-by-case basis.